# Angular material CSS is not working on Click event in Mobile

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add custom CSS in angular material. I am using mat-selection-list. Onclick event it will change colour to orange.

Right no when user is clicking it is not updating right away. It only select particular option or change colour when user click on another option

here is the example of the code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmlqc3

Comment: What browser are you in? This updates right away for me (Chrome)

Comment: It works for me too(I used Chrome). I think there is a browser compatibility Issues.

Comment: So it worked on one phone, not another. I'll look some more into it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: i used the chrome as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the order of classes being applied are conflicting with your style vs material. I noticed on the latest mobile browser that the following style:

```
@media (hover: none)
<style>…</style>
.mat-list-option:not(.mat-list-item-disabled):hover, .mat-nav-list .mat-list-item:not(.mat-list-item-disabled):hover {
    background: 0 0;
}
```

is the latest applied, while yours is farther down the list.

I don't know if this is the best fix, but, changing your class to have:

```
background: rgba(249, 105, 14, 1) !important;
```

fixes the issue.